# Django Query ManyToMany field as list

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I want to query a manytomany field an save it directly as a list.

Here is my query:

```
inventory_list = list(Inventory.objects.filter(inventory_plant__plant_name = ikey ,inventory_product__pc1_product=ikey2).values(
        'inventory_number',
        'inventory_name',
        'inventory_process_name__process_name'
    ))
```

Here my result:

```
inventory_list = [{'inventory_number': 1211267, 'inventory_name': 'Käfig1', 'inventory_process_name__process_name': 'Turning'}, {'inventory_number': 1211267, 'inventory_name': 'Käfig1', 'inventory_process_name__process_name': 'Grinding'}, {'inventory_number': 1211267, 'inventory_name': 'Käfig1', 'inventory_process_name__process_name': 'Heat Treatment'}, {'inventory_number': 1217729, 'inventory_name': 'Käfig2', 'inventory_process_name__process_name': 'Grinding'}]
```

What I want is, that the processes are directly in a list, depending on the 'inventory_number':

```
inventory_list = [{'inventory_number': 1211267, 'inventory_name': 'Käfig1', 'inventory_process_name__process_name': ['Turning', 'Grinding', 'Heat Treatment']}, 
{'inventory_number': 1217729, 'inventory_name': 'Käfig2', 'inventory_process_name__process_name': 'Grinding'}]
```

Here is my Model:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Inventory Number", unique=True)
    inventory_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Inventory Name")
    inventory_process_name = models.ManyToManyField(Process, verbose_name="Processes")
    inventory_plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, verbose_name="Plant",   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inventory_product = models.ManyToManyField(TPZProductCluster1, verbose_name="TPZ Product Cluster 1")
    inventory_pot_per_shift = models.IntegerField(validators= [MaxValueValidator(600), MinValueValidator(0)], verbose_name="Pot per Shift in min")
    inventory_working_weeks_per_year = models.IntegerField(validators= [MaxValueValidator(52), MinValueValidator(0)], verbose_name="Working Weeks per year")
    inventory_comments = models.TextField(max_length=1000 ,verbose_name="Comments", blank=True)
    inventory_responsible_person = models.ForeignKey(ResponsiblePerson, verbose_name="Responsible Person", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['inventory_number']
        verbose_name = 'Inventory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Inventories'
    def processes(self):
        return ', '.join([p.process_name for p in self.inventory_process_name.all()])
    def products(self):
        return ', '.join([p.pc1_product for p in self.inventory_product.all()])
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.inventory_number) + ', ' + self.inventory_name
```

Is there a direct way to query the data or can I do it just after the query?

Thank you very much in advance!!!!

Comment: In your model, `Inventory_number` field has `unique=True`, then how can multiple objects have same `Inventory_number` ?

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your answer.
One inventory_number can have multible processes.

Comment: Are you using DRF?

Comment: Hello, no I'm using ordinary Django.